# https creating issue in csv export in php zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, https, header, export-to-csv

I am using php zend1 , I am trying to export csv but I am getting https / ssl error like "Your connection is not private".

I am trying to export csv

```
public function exportsubscriberAction ()
    {
        $subscriberList = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('ns.*')->from("NewsletterSubscription ns");
        $res = $subscriberList->fetchArray();
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Email');        
        $column = 2;        
        foreach ($res as $subscriber) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet ()->setCellValue ( 'A' . $column, $subscriber['email'] );      
            $column ++;
        }
        $headerStyle = array ('fill' => array ('type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'color' => array ('rgb' => '#FFFFFF' ) ), 'font' => array ('bold' => true ) );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet ()->getStyle ( 'A1:' . 'B1' )->applyFromArray ( $headerStyle );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet ()->getColumnDimension ( 'A' )->setAutoSize ( true );
        header ( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' );
        header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="subscriberList.xlsx"' );
        header ( 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' );
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter ( $objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007' );
        $objWriter->save ( 'php://output' );
    }
```

Your connection is not private
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: It is working on local but on server , it is not working . I have done lots of research , and I think something is wrong in header
header ( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' );
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="subscriberList.xlsx"' );
header ( 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' );

Comment: Those headers have nothing to do with HTTPS. Start debugging by checking what is actually happening on the network level in your browser dev tools.

Comment: Nothing is showing in networks under inspect , please check headers and let me know it needs modifications..

Comment: As I said already, there is no apparent reason to assume that these headers had anything to do with the problem in the first place. And that there would be _nothing_ to see in the network panel, that does not make sense - you are getting an error message about a problem with your HTTPS connection, which could hardly be the case, if there wasn’t _any_ request.